# blade with bootstrap form wont work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I am having some issues with bootstrap and blade. I am very unsure where to put form::open and form::close to make the form work with bootstrap code.

```
 {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/insertHT', 'method' => 'POST')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

  <div class="form-group">

    <label  class="col-md-2 control-label">Basseng: </label>
    <div class="col-md-3">

     {{ Form::select('pool_id', $pools, Input::old('pool_id'), array('placeholder'=>'Basseng', 'class' => 'form-control' )) }} 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-3 control-label">Badende Per Time: </label>
    <div class="col-md-2" >
      {{ Form::text('T_Badende_per_Time', Input::old('T_Badende_per_Time'), array('placeholder'=>'', 'class' => 'form-control' ))  }}  
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-3 control-label">Temperatur: </label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     {{ Form::text('T_Temperatur', Input::old('T_Temperatur'), array('placeholder'=>'', 'class' => 'form-control' )) }}  


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
       {{ Form::submit('Lagre', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

EDIT:

When I put the form:open first before form class:"form-horizontal" it looks like this and the form works and inserts into database:

[image]

but when I put it after form class:"form-horizontal", it looks perfect, but form doesnt work:

[image]

Comment: simply replace <form...> and </form> with blade snippets, it works like a charm. You don't put it before/after, remove html tags <form></form> with blade ones, add class like @ceejayoz suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form::open()` and `Form::close()` **replace** your `<form>` tags.

To add the bootstrap class to the generated `<form>` tag, you'd pass it as an argument:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/insertHT', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
```